# Change default style based on title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to change the default style based on title of the page.I found that as the easiest way to accomplish needs.

I load the default styling option in header.php file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" data-them="" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

I suppose `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>` loads style.css which is on same path as header.php

I commented out this the line    `<link rel="stylesheet" data-them="" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />` and tried to check title with php, based on that condition I wanted to load different style.css file.

```
<?php 
    $title = get_the_title();

    if($title === "Title1"){
        ?><link rel="stylesheet" data-them="" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" /><?php
    }
    elseif($title === "Title2"){
          ?><link rel="stylesheet" data-them="" href="style2.css" type="text/css" media="all" /><?php
    }
    else{
         ?><link rel="stylesheet" data-them="" href="style3.css" type="text/css" media="all" /><?php
    } 
?>
```

This code does not work for me and not sure why.. Styling is messed up

Answer (score 0):

Please dequeue default style using below function.

```
wp_dequeue_style('default-style');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please find below style in your theme. Mostly enqueue in functions.php file.

EX: 
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentynineteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), 
wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) );

Please add below line after your theme's default style. 
(get_stylesheet_uri())

wp_dequeue_style('twentynineteen-style');
```

After that check it your issue.